# Discord PY | How to get user name and user discriminator (name#0000)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I’m making a bot that says the username and the discriminator of a user (`name#0000`, not `79864895723845345`)
[image: Example]

I’m currently using discord.py rewrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you mean username and **discriminator**. The discriminator is the 4 numbers behind.

Answering your question, you can do:

```
str(user)
```

which is likely shorthand for:

```
user.username+"#"+str(user.discriminator)
```

Where `user` is your user object.

Comment: Ooooh ok thx. I dont know what that name is

Comment: No problem. Btw get used to reading the documentation if you need to clarify on the methods and attributes available: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/